# Bootstrap thumbnails don't work well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to create a simple site using it. I want to use thumbnails to create an image gallery with 3 columns. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <header class="span12 hero-unit">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="The Art Conference" class="pull-right">
      <h1>The Art Conference</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more</a></p>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div clas="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span4">
        <article class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
          <h3>Jennifer Jerome</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus nibh justo, ac sollicitudin dolor aliquam sit amet. Pellentesque facilisis mollis rutrum. Sed ac lectus vestibulum, lacinia justo sed, porta sapien. In euismod pulvinar condimentum. Mauris eget laoreet ante. Phasellus ultrices libero eget magna egestas, sit amet laoreet quam gravida. Duis posuere eu libero ac feugiat.</p>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li class="span4">
        <article class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
          <h3>Jonathan Ferrar</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus nibh justo, ac sollicitudin dolor aliquam sit amet. Pellentesque facilisis mollis rutrum. Sed ac lectus vestibulum, lacinia justo sed, porta sapien. In euismod pulvinar condimentum. Mauris eget laoreet ante. Phasellus ultrices libero eget magna egestas, sit amet laoreet quam gravida. Duis posuere eu libero ac feugiat.</p>
        </article>
      </li>

      <li class="span4">
        <article class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
          <h3>Levonne Larue</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus nibh justo, ac sollicitudin dolor aliquam sit amet. Pellentesque facilisis mollis rutrum. Sed ac lectus vestibulum, lacinia justo sed, porta sapien. In euismod pulvinar condimentum. Mauris eget laoreet ante. Phasellus ultrices libero eget magna egestas, sit amet laoreet quam gravida. Duis posuere eu libero ac feugiat.</p>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

When rendered on a browser such as Chrome, it's not aligned.
Image: http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/6195/bootstrapproblem1.jpg

Did I miss something?.

P/s: I use Bootstrap v2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your code. Try changing `<div clas="row-fluid">` to `<div class="row-fluid">`.